# What is Cov(X,Y) when X,Y is a F-distribution (a,b) and (c,d) ,in case X,Y Not independent

Tags: multivariate-analysis, random-variable, covariance, covariance-matrix, f-distribution

I want to know Covariance of random variable between $X$ and $Y$ when $X$ is a F-distribution with degree of freedom $a$ and $b$ and $Y$ is a F-distribution with degree of freedom $c$ and $d$,in case $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

I explained more about my question

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help that you are able to provide.

Comment: What is the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$? Absent that, how long is a piece of string.

Comment: Dear wolfies,  

In case, X and Y are independent random variable. I know joint pdf of X and Y.

But in this case, X and Y are not independent, So I can not know joint pdf of X and Y.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Dear wolfies, Which part do not you not understand my question ??.

Comment: With the information you have given, the only we can say is that the covariance is a number somewhere between $-\infty$ and $\infty$.  So you need to give us some more. First, please tell us in which context your question arises.

Comment: Dear kjetil b halvorsen, I mean in general form of Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) -E(X)E(Y) when X,Y has F-distribution. Does not mean covariance of data.

Comment: The covariance cannot be determined from this information. Presumably in the case you are interested in, you know something more about the dependence than just "not independent" - it might be helpful to explain how these distributions arise

Comment: Dear Juho Kokkala, I'm sorry for the unclear question. I have solved my question. you can checked again.

Comment: Please edit the information into the text rather than by adding a picture

Comment: Dear Juho Kokkala, Sorry i use this site for the first time. I do not know how to write symbols or equations.

Comment: This may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#LaTeX   (though based on a quick glance I think the question itself is somewhat unclear - how do the "sample covariance matrices" arise or how they are related to the random vectors $\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathbf{X}_2$?

Comment: You have not stated the relationship between $X_1$ and $X_2$

Comment: Dear Juho Kokkala,wolfies. I have solved my question. you can checked again.
Note:matrix X1  and X2 are Independent.